# Error while compiling my c++ program

Tags: c++

I am a c++ beginner and after reading many articles on good ways to learn programming, I have found that its a good practice to learn programming through using command line interface than through IDE's. So therefore I am trying to learn c++ through command line interface. I am following my first tutorial of a "hello world" program. I am using MinGW compiler to compile my code. As I try to compile my code in the windows command prompt, I am getting an error. I have searched throughout the internet but can't seem to find an answer for this problem. The command I use to compile my code is "g++ Motto.cpp -o Motto.exe" and I get the problem "g++:error:CreateProcess:No such file or directory". I have checked for the path environment variable and it has the MinGW path. I have also checked the MinGW folder and found that all the executives needed are installed. Please help me fix the problem.

Here is the code:

```
 #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the command you ran to compile it?

Comment: please help us by telling us what *exactly* you are doing… e.g. the command line invocation of `g++`.

Comment: "g++ Motto.cpp -o Motto.cpp

Comment: try `g++ -o Motto Motto.cpp`

Comment: I am trying to compile and run my c++ program in command prompt

Comment: Got a feeling you might have trashed `motto.cpp`

Comment: "g++ -o Motto Motto.cpp", I tried but i am getting the same error

Comment: Show: 1) the actual code you are trying to compile. 2) the exact compiler command line you use to build it. 3) the *_exact and complete_* error you get (copy and paste it).

Comment: #include <iostream>

int main()
{
 std::cout << "Hello world\n";
 return 0;
}

Comment: I am using windows command prompt and am compiling using MinGW compiler

Comment: C:\Users\User\Desktop\programming files>g++ Motto.cpp -o Motto.exe
g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually means the g++ cannot find some executables that it needs to run during the compilation. Especially with MinGW the installation can be little tricky.

Make sure the paths to the MinGW installation is in your PATH environment variable (`echo %PATH%`) and also try to restart the computer.

If you installed manually and not with the MinGW installer (mingw-get), make sure you have downloaded and installed all the prerequisities (core, c++, binutils, runtime, etc.).

The `g++ --version` only prints the version, so it does not need to call another executables which the compilation does (like cc/c++, ar, etc).

Check the bin folder inside your MinGW installation directory, if you have at least those executables there: cc, c++, c++filt, ld (and others like ar, as).

Also, check {MinGWDir}\libexec\gcc\mingw32{version} if it contains cc1, cc1plus, collect2.

Comment: I have checked my path environmental variable, and I also checked for the executives and I found that they are installed properly

Comment: Did you install manually or by using mingw-get? If manually, try to repeat with mingw-get. In general, for beginner I would recommend to use [Microsoft Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) - it is easier to install and comes with a pretty good IDE (for free).

Comment: Thanks for the tip in the comment. I tried reinstalling it and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try running "make $file-you-want", or like @FCo said, "g++ -o Motto Motto.cpp", The error means that you're passing it an invalid filename to compile, or you're not in the proper directory. Make sure you have the file you want to compile in your working directory, either by typing "ls" or "dir" depending on the system you're using.

Information that would help answer this question:

- What you're doing to cause the error (how are you running g++?)
- What OS/Environment you're running on

Comment: I am running on windows 7 platform.

Comment: I am writing my text file using notepad++ and I have saved the file in my folder. I have navigated to the folder using command line and am trying to compile and run it using MinGW compiler by typing the command "g++ Motto.cpp -o Motto.exe

Comment: I tried typing "dir" and it also shows that the file "Motto.cpp" is there in the directory